# Model works for single layer but errors for batch process

Tags: qgis-3, batch, qgis-modeler

I have a pretty simple model in QGIS that I am trying to use as a batch process.

The model takes a line shapefile input, creates a temporary buffer, extracts by location using that created buffer, and then merges the extracted location shapefile with originally inputted line file.

When I execute it on a single layer it works fine and outputs as desired, however, when I try to use it as a batch process it errors out.

The Python error that kicks up:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchAlgorithmDialog.py", line 88, in runAlgorithm parameters[param.name()] = wrapper.parameterValue()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterValue'

And the model:

[image: model]

Comment: I'm having the same problem! @Enrich Purpur (sorry I can't reply directly to you because of my insufficient reputation), your solution sounds promising. How would you run the script for multiple layers though? I.e. as a stand-in for the faulty batch process. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/166056)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/166056)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a python solution for you.

But before starting, you can always ask the python console for help in populating the parameters like this:

```
print(help(processing.algorithmHelp('qgis:buffer'))
print(help(processing.algorithmHelp('qgis:extractbylocation'))
print(help(processing.algorithmHelp('qgis:mergevectorlayers'))
```

Also, to populate the dictionaries I used to run these three tools, I first ran the widget. Then I looked in the log panel for the results and directly copied the python code from that into the dictionaries.

```
import processing


buffer_parameters = {
'INPUT' : '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Example.gpkg|layername=Example',
'DISTANCE' : 0.01,      #this is in decimal degrees, yours will probably be different
'SEGMENTS' : 5,
'END_CAP_STYLE' : 0,
'MITER_LIMIT' : 2,
'DISSOLVE' : False,
'OUTPUT' : 'memory:'}

buffer = processing.run('qgis:buffer', buffer_parameters)

extraction_parameters = {
'INPUT': 'Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&field=fid:long&uid={d7feac26-7116-4f01-b1ba-866501ab700b}',         #this is a memory layer, yours could be different
'PREDICATE': [0],
'INTERSECT': 'Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&field=fid:long&uid={d7feac26-7116-4f01-b1ba-866501ab700b}',     #this is also a memory layer
'OUTPUT' : 'memory:'}

extract_by_location = processing.run('qgis:extractbylocation', extraction_parameters)

merge_parameters = {
'LAYERS': ['/Users/ep9k/Desktop/Example2.shp','Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326&field=fid:long&uid={f2afdb7d-4ff4-4850-99c0-43d5989c54fd}'],       #this is just a list of layers
'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:102003'),
'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}

merge_vector_layers = processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:mergevectorlayers', merge_parameters)     #notice mergeAndLoadResults here, I want to see this output
```

Let me know if you have further questions.