# Error while running batch processing in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, batch, qgis-modeler

I have built a straightforward model in the Graphical Modeller in QGIS 3.4 to select features by expression and then save the selected features to a new shapefile.

[image: example1]

It works when running singly but fails when run as a batch process with the following message:

[image: example2]

The same model in QGIS 2.14 works when run both individually and as a batch process.

I have seen similar questions [QGIS- Model works on single layer execution, errors out when run as batch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325255/qgis-model-works-on-single-layer-execution-errors-out-when-run-as-batch) but no explanation or indication how to get around this in QGIS 3 (apart from using 2.14 or writing a Python script).

Is this a known issue? Or is there a fix to get it to work in QGIS 3?

I am trying to demonstrate this feature to students - my current plan is to use QGIS 2.14 for this part of the workshop.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I would report it on the QGIS bug tracker: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues